# Firebase signup with phone and email and then set password at first login

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a mobile app with **user signup by email and password** working correctly. I want to change it as mentioned below.

---

I want to **signup a user with his email and phone number without specifying the password**. This is done by a system admin. Then at the first signing in, the user should be able to **do a phone auth and then set the password.**
Do firebase support this? If yes, can someone point me out how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with an email and phone number using the Admin SDK:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'user@example.com',
  phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
});
```

Then the user can sign in with the phone number from your app via client SDK. On sign in, you check if the password is set. If not, you ask the user to set the password via `updatePassword`.
Here is a snippet using the JS SDK:

```
const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput();
const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
  'sign-in-button',
  {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': function(response) {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      onSignInSubmit();
    }
  });
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
  .then((confirmationResult) => {
    // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
    // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
    ...
    return confirmationResult.confirm(smsCode);
  }).then((userCredential) => {
    // Check if password exists.
    if (!(userCredential.user.providerData[1] &&
          userCredential.user.providerData[1].providerId === 'password')) {
      // Ask user for the new password.
      ...
      // Save the password.
      return userCredential.user.updatePassword(password);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Error; SMS not sent
    // ...
  });
```

The above can be done on all platforms that Firebase supports.

Comment: What is the usage of `window.recaptchVerifier` here?

Comment: I got it from the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more thing to clarify; can we use admin-sdk in cloud functions to create the user when a request is sent / when a data is put into the database?

Comment: You can create the user in a cloud function in theory but you need to provide more info on how your flow is structured.